# VHDL: Traffic Light State Machine not Synthesizing

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

So I'm creating a Traffic Light State Machine and I'm having a couple of issues with my code synthesizing. I've been trying to work it out for ages.

### Issues:

1. Counter Module not being connected with other modules

**TopLevel Schematic:** Viewable at https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8dRk.png

**TopLevel**.vhdl

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;


entity TopLevel is Port ( MasterReset : in  STD_LOGIC;
       Clock : in  STD_LOGIC;
       CarEW : in  STD_LOGIC;
       CarNS : in  STD_LOGIC;
       PedEW : in  STD_LOGIC;
       PedNS : in  STD_LOGIC;
       debugLED : out  STD_LOGIC;
       Lights : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0));
end TopLevel;

architecture Behavioral of TopLevel is

-- Synchronized Button inputs --
signal PedEWButton : STD_LOGIC;
signal PedNSButton : STD_LOGIC;
signal CarEWButton : STD_LOGIC;
signal CarNSButton : STD_LOGIC;

--Reset, Clear and Count Signals --
signal ClearRegister : STD_LOGIC;
signal ResetCounter : STD_LOGIC;
signal Count: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (8 downto 0);
-- Registered Ped Signals --
signal PedEWReg : STD_LOGIC;
signal PedNSReg : STD_LOGIC;



begin
-- Check For MasterReset and Sync Inputs
process (MasterReset, clock, CarEWButton, CarNSButton, PedEWButton, PedNSButton)
begin
    if (MasterReset = '1') then
        debugLED <= '1';
        CarNSButton <= '1';
        CarEWButton <= '1';
        PedEWButton <= '1';
        PedNSButton <= '1';
    elsif rising_edge(clock) then
        CarEWButton <= CarEW;
        CarNSButton <= CarNS;
        PedEWButton <= PedEW;
        PedNSButton <= PedNS;
    end if;
end process;

-- Instantiate State Machine --
StateMachine:
entity work.TrafficStatesMachine
Port Map (
                MasterReset => MasterReset,
                Clock => Clock,
                CarEWButton => CarEWButton,
                CarNSButton => CarNSButton,
                PedEWButton => PedEWReg, 
                PedNSButton => PedNSReg,
                Counter => Count,
                Lights => Lights,
                ResetCounter => ResetCounter,
                ClearRegister => ClearRegister
                );

-- Instantiate Counter --
Counter:
entity work.Counter
    Port Map (
                MasterReset => MasterReset,
                ResetCounter => ResetCounter,
                Clock => Clock,
                Counter => Count
                );

-- Instantiate PedRegister --
PedRegister:
entity work.PedRegister
    Port Map (
                PedNSButton => PedNSButton,
                PedEWButton => PedEWButton,
                PedNSRegOut => PedNSReg,
                PedEWRegOut => PedEWReg,
                ClearRegister => ClearRegister
                );

end architecture Behavioral;
```

**TrafficStatesMachine**.vhdl

```
--===================================================================
-- Traffic states Machine
--
-- A states Machine to interpret and manage traffic
-- 
--===================================================================
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity TrafficStatesMachine is
Port (
    MasterReset     : IN std_logic;
    Clock     : IN std_logic;
    CarEWButton     : IN std_logic;
    CarNSButton     : IN std_logic;
    PedEWButton     : IN std_logic;
    PedNSButton     : IN std_logic;
    Counter   : IN std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);
    ResetCounter : OUT std_logic;
    ClearRegister : OUT std_logic;
    Lights : OUT std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
    );
end TrafficStatesMachine;

architecture Behavioural of TrafficStatesMachine is
type states_type is (EWCarGreen, EWPedGreen, EWAmber, NSCarGreen, NSPedGreen, NSAmber );

signal states: states_type;

begin
process( MasterReset, Clock, CarEWButton, CarNSButton, PedEWButton, PedNSButton, Counter )

begin
    if (MasterReset = '1') then
        states <= EWCarGreen;
    elsif rising_edge(clock) then
        case states is
            when EWCarGreen =>
                ClearRegister <= '0';
                if (Counter < "111111111") then
                    if (PedEWButton  = '1') then
                        if (CarNSButton  = '0') and (PedNSButton  = '0') then
                            states <= EWPedGreen;
                            ResetCounter <= '1';
                        else
                            states <= EWCarGreen;
                        end if;
                    end if;
                elsif (Counter = "111111111") then
                    if (CarNSButton  = '1') then
                        states <= EWAmber;
                        ResetCounter <= '1';
                    elsif (PedNSButton  = '1') then
                        states <= EWAmber;
                        ResetCounter <= '1';
                    else
                        states <= EWCarGreen;
                    end if;
                end if;

            when EWPedGreen =>
                ClearRegister <= '1';
                ResetCounter <= '0';
                if (Counter = "110010000") then
                    states <= EWCarGreen;
                else
                    states <= EWPedGreen;
                end if;

            when EWAmber =>
                ResetCounter <= '0';
                if (Counter = "011001000") then
                    if (PedNSButton  = '1') then
                        states <= NSPedGreen;
                        ResetCounter <= '1';
                    else
                        states <= NSCarGreen;
                        ResetCounter <= '1';
                    end if;
                else
                    states <= EWAmber;
                end if;

            when NSCarGreen =>
                ResetCounter <= '0';
                ClearRegister <= '0';
                if (Counter < "111111111") then
                    if (PedNSButton  = '1') then
                        if (CarEWButton = '0') and (PedEWButton = '0') then
                            states <= NSPedGreen;
                            ResetCounter <= '1';
                        else
                            states <= NSCarGreen;
                        end if;
                    end if;
                elsif (Counter = "111111111") then
                    if (CarEWButton  = '1') then
                        states <= NSAmber;
                        ResetCounter <= '1';
                    elsif (PedEWButton  = '1') then
                        states <= NSAmber;
                        ResetCounter <= '1';
                    else
                        states <= NSCarGreen;
                    end if;
                end if;

            when NSPedGreen =>
                ResetCounter <= '0';
                ClearRegister <= '1';
                if (Counter = "110010000") then
                    states <= NSCarGreen;
                else
                    states <= NSPedGreen;
                end if;

            when NSAmber =>
                ResetCounter <= '0';
                if (Counter = "011001000") then
                    if (PedEWButton  = '1') then 
                        states <= EWPedGreen;
                        ResetCounter <= '1';
                    else
                        states <= EWCarGreen;
                        ResetCounter <= '1';
                    end if;
                else
                    states <= NSAmber;
                end if;

        end case;
    end if;
end process;

process( states )

begin
    case states is
        when EWCarGreen => lights <= "0010";
        when EWPedGreen => lights <= "0011";
        when EWAmber => lights <= "0001";
        when NSCarGreen => lights <= "1000";
        when NSPedGreen => lights <= "1100";
        when NSAmber => lights <= "0100";
        when others => lights <= "0010";
    end case;
end process;

end Behavioural;
```

**Counter**.vhdl

```
--=================================================================== 
-- Counter.vhdl 
-- A counter to give time delays
--=================================================================== 
library IEEE; 
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL; 
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL; 
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL; 

entity Counter is
Port ( MasterReset : in std_logic; 
        Clock : in std_logic; 
        ResetCounter : in std_logic;
        Counter : out std_logic_vector(8 downto 0)); 

end entity Counter; 

architecture Behavioural of Counter is

signal Count : std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);

begin 
Counter <= Count;
-- Produce Count sequence from 0 ... 512 
process( MasterReset, Clock, ResetCounter) 
begin 
    if (MasterReset = '1') then
        Count <= "000000000"; -- start count from 0
    elsif rising_edge(clock) then
        if (ResetCounter = '1') then 
            Count <= "000000000";
        elsif (Count < "111111111") then
            Count <= Count + "000000001";
        else 
            Count <= "111111111";
        end if;
    end if; 
end process;

end architecture Behavioural;
```

**PedRegister**.vhdl

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity PedRegister is
Port ( ClearRegister : in STD_LOGIC;
          PedNSButton: in  STD_LOGIC;
       PedEWButton : in  STD_LOGIC;
       PedNSRegOut : out  STD_LOGIC;
       PedEWRegOut : out  STD_LOGIC);
end PedRegister;

architecture Behavioral of PedRegister is
signal PedNSReg : STD_LOGIC;
signal PedEWReg : STD_LOGIC;

begin
PedNSRegOut <= PedNSReg;
PedEWRegOut <= PedEWReg;

process (PedNSButton, PedEWButton, ClearRegister)
begin

    if ClearRegister = '1' then
            PedNSReg <='0';
    elsif PedNSButton = '1' then
            PedNSReg <='1';
    else 
        PedNSReg <= '0';
    end if;


    if ClearRegister = '1' then
            PedEWReg <= '0';
    elsif PedEWButton = '1' then
            PedEWReg <='1';
    else
        PedEWReg <= '0';
    end if;
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

**TopLevel**.ucf

```
##################################################
#                                                #
#  Pin Assignments for Digilent C-Mod C2 Module  #
#  Traffic Light Hardware                        #
#                                                #
##################################################

#  The C-MOD Pin numbers are shown in the COMMENTS=20
#  e.g. CMOD-P35 is pin 35 of the module and is (usualy) used for the = Clock input

# The following 3 CPLD pins have special on-chip Clock buffers
# Usually uncomment one Clock line as required
NET "Clock"  LOC =3D "p1"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33;    # CMOD-P35 - GCK2, = Global Clock input
#NET "Clock"  LOC =3D "p43"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33;  # CMOD-P33 - GCK0, = Global Clock input, May be used for I/O
#NET "Clock"  LOC =3D "p44"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33;  # CMOD-P34 - GCK1, = Global Clock input, May be used for I/O

# System level constraints
Net      Clock TNM_NET =3D Clock;
Timespec TS_Clock =3D PERIOD Clock 1 us; # adjust to suit Clock

# Convenient to allocate a Reset pin
NET "MasterReset"     LOC =3D "p30"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33; # CMOD-P18 - = GSR, Global Set/Reset
Net "Reset" TIG; # No timing constraint on system reset

#NET "" LOC =3D "p12"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33; # CMOD-P1
#NET "" LOC =3D "p13"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33; # CMOD-P2
#NET "" LOC =3D "p14"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33; # CMOD-P3
#NET "" LOC =3D "p16"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33; # CMOD-P4
# CMOD-P5-8 - N/C
#NET "" LOC =3D "p18"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33; # CMOD-P9
NET "debugLED" LOC =3D "p19"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33; # CMOD-P10
#NET "clockLED" LOC =3D "p20"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33; # CMOD-P11
#NET "" LOC =3D "p21"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33; # CMOD-P12
#NET "" LOC =3D "p22"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33; # CMOD-P13
#NET "" LOC =3D "p23"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33; # CMOD-P14
#NET "LEDs&lt;0&gt;" LOC =3D "p27"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33; # CMOD-P15
#NET "LEDs&lt;1&gt;" LOC =3D "p28"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33; # CMOD-P16
#NET "LEDs&lt;2&gt;" LOC =3D "p29"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33; # CMOD-P17
# CMOD-P18 - GSR, Global Set/Reset - see above
# CMOD-P19 - N/C
# CMOD-P20 - Vcc
# CMOD-P21 - Gnd
#NET "" LOC =3D "p31"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33; # CMOD-P22 - GTS2, Global = Tristate control
#NET "" LOC =3D "p32"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33; # CMOD-P23 - GTS3, Global = Tristate control
#NET "" LOC =3D "p33"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33; # CMOD-P24 - GTS0, Global = Tristate control
#NET "" LOC =3D "p34"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33; # CMOD-P25 - GTS1, Global = Tristate control
NET "CarEW"       LOC =3D "p36"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33; # CMOD-P26
NET "CarNS"       LOC =3D "p37"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33; # CMOD-P27
NET "PedEW"       LOC =3D "p38"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33; # CMOD-P28
NET "PedNS"       LOC =3D "p39"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33; # CMOD-P29
NET "Lights<0>" LOC =3D "p40"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33; # CMOD-P30
NET "Lights<1>" LOC =3D "p41"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33; # CMOD-P31
NET "Lights<2>" LOC =3D "p42"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33; # CMOD-P32
NET "Lights<3>" LOC =3D "p43"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33; # CMOD-P33 - = GCK0, Global Clock input, May be used for I/O
#NET "Clock"  LOC =3D "p44"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33;  # CMOD-P34 - GCK1, = Global Clock input, May be used for I/O
# CMOD-P35 - GCK1, Global Clock inputs, see above
#NET "" LOC =3D "p2"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33; # CMOD-P35
#NET "" LOC =3D "p3"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33; # CMOD-P36
#NET "" LOC =3D "p4"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33; # CMOD-P37
#NET "" LOC =3D "p5"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33; # CMOD-P38
#NET "" LOC =3D "p6"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33; # CMOD-P39
#NET "" LOC =3D "p8"|IOSTANDARD=3DLVCMOS33; # CMOD-P40
```

Comment: The obvious question is all the more relevant since you didn't include the testbench : did it work in simulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a similar situation was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674062/wires-are-not-connected-in-the-rtl)

in this case it was an issue with Xilinx ISE version. I copied your code and checked it with ISE 13.4 and the counter is connected [image: screenShot]

however, relevant for your function is the "real" synthesis (check synthesis report) and not the RTL schematic visualisatoin.